# How can I generate this 3-D matrix without for loops in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'd like to generate an N-by-N-by-3 matrix `A` such that `A(:,:,i) = eye(n)*i`. How can I do this without using for loops (i.e. in a vectorized fashion)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an older version of MATLAB before BSXFUN was introduced, consider this option (the same answer as the one by [@Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392021/matlab-how-to-generate-3d-matrix-with-this-sequence/4392223#4392223)):

```
N = 4; M = 3;
A = repmat(eye(N),[1 1 M]) .* repmat(permute(1:M,[3 1 2]),[N N 1])

A(:,:,1) =
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1
A(:,:,2) =
     2     0     0     0
     0     2     0     0
     0     0     2     0
     0     0     0     2
A(:,:,3) =
     3     0     0     0
     0     3     0     0
     0     0     3     0
     0     0     0     3
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use the functions [KRON](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/kron.html) and [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html):

```
>> N = 4;
>> A = reshape(kron(1:3,eye(N)),[N N 3])

A(:,:,1) =

     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1

A(:,:,2) =

     2     0     0     0
     0     2     0     0
     0     0     2     0
     0     0     0     2

A(:,:,3) =

     3     0     0     0
     0     3     0     0
     0     0     3     0
     0     0     0     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html), multiplying the identity matrix with a 1-by-1-by-3 array of `1,2,3`

```
>> bsxfun(@times,eye(4),permute(1:3,[3,1,2]))
ans(:,:,1) =
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1
ans(:,:,2) =
     2     0     0     0
     0     2     0     0
     0     0     2     0
     0     0     0     2
ans(:,:,3) =
     3     0     0     0
     0     3     0     0
     0     0     3     0
     0     0     0     3
```

Comment: @Quiang Li: Looks like it appeared first in r2007a.